# How to remove a directory from the %PATH% variable by cmd

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd, environment-variables, substring

It's easy enough to add a directory to a variable and to an environment variable by commandline. It took a lot of struggle, but I was able to remove a substring from a variable as you can see down below (although it did leave pesky `%` sign for some reason). At any rate, as you can see below what works with `set` does not work with `setx`. Is there any way do remove directories/paths from the `%PATH%` environment variable by commandline?

For testing I did, `echo %path%`:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\LibreSSL\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\addtopath;C:\Users\thisguy\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;\\test\test
```

What I want to do here is remove the `\\test\test` at the very end by commandline. So,

```
set cut=\\test\test
echo %cut%
\\test\test
```

Next, I set `%path%` to `oldname`:

```
set oldname=%path%
echo %oldname%
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\LibreSSL\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\addtopath;C:\Users\thisguy\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;\\test\test
```

It works, so far so good.

Now the trick to removing `\\test\test` is using `call` with some basic variable editing. Go ahead, try this some other way, it took me forever to figure this part out:

```
call set newname=%%oldname:%cut%=%%
echo %newname%
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\LibreSSL\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\addtopath;C:\Users\thisguy\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;% **<--------(pesky percent sign lingers)**
```

Genius! I'm super happy right now. So, all is pretty good for the most part, right? Well check this out:

```
call setx path=%%path:%cut%=%%
```

And what do I get?

```
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).
```

It should work exactly the same, shouldn't it? I don't care how this gets solved, I just want to be able to delete a directory location from `%PATH%` from commandline.

Comment: Welcome! Please post your code and results as text in the question.

Comment: `setx` writes to `HKCU` hive by default if the `/M` argument is not used. So you are updating the value in the `PATH` key in the registry key of `HKCU\Environment`?. **Note**: `%PATH%` environmental variable is a merged value of `PATH` from the hives of `HKLM` and of `HKCU`.

Comment: Helps if you actually read the help file for the command before you try to use it and come asking for help.

Comment: Just to note, _because you have several repeated entries_, when you've finished messing with `%PATH%`, it should look like this: `C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\LibreSSL\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\thisguy\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin`. I assumed that `C:\addtopath` wasn't supposed to be there either, so I removed it, _please feel free to add it to the end if it's needed!_

Comment: michael_heath, I'm not using the /m argument because I don't want it to affect the whole system but myself only. Good observation on how %PATH% merges HKLM and HKCU, which accounts for *some* duplicates when I echo %PATH%.


Mofi, thanks for your input, I cleaned it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd investigate why that terminal `%` persists - it doesn't on my machine.

Your problem appears to be that since the resultant `path` contains spaces, you need to quote the value to be assigned. It would also help if you were to use the correct syntax for `setx` - the `=` is at best superfluous.

```
call setx path "%%path:%cut%=%%"
```

should work happily, although I'd suggest you set a dummy variable for testing, just in case as `path` is a critical variable.